# How to remove an element from a list based on Inner-Text

Tags: jquery, html

I have a UL which is automatically generated by a CMS which i use. I cannot make any changes to the server side code. So i decided to make my changes using jQuery.

I have the following situation.

[HERE IS A JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/yc2bxvs8/1/)

I have a list of Manufacturers generated by my CMS and i need to trim it down to my preferences. So the list looks a bit like follows

```
2-POWER
TP-LINK
TRIUMPH AD
UTOUCH
VANGUARD
Western Digital
WHIPTAIL
WYSE
Xerox
XMINI
YAMAHA
Zyxel
```

I want to trim down this list according to my preferences.

Basically what i want is to only show the list of manufacturers that I want and to remove the rest.I think my select part of the Jquery isn't good enough and fails.

```
$("select[id$='ManufacturerContainer'] option[value!='Xerox']").remove();
```

HTML(ONLY PART HTML)

```
<div id="ManufacturerContainer">
    <div class="RadTreeView RadTreeView_ ManufacturerTreeView">
        <ul class="rtUL">
            <li class="rtLI rtFirst">
                <div class="rtTop"> <span class="rtSp"></span>
                    <div class="rtIn">
                        <div class="rtTemplate" style="display: block;">    <a href="/Products/tabid/85/rvdsfmfid/2-power-11/Default.aspx">
                2-POWER</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="rtLI">
                <div class="rtMid"> <span class="rtSp"></span>
                    <div class="rtIn">
                        <div class="rtTemplate" style="display: block;">    <a href="/Products/tabid/85/rvdsfmfid/tp-link-243/Default.aspx">
                TP-LINK</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>           
            <li class="rtLI rtLast">
                <div class="rtBot"> <span class="rtSp"></span>

                    <div class="rtIn">
                        <div class="rtTemplate" style="display: block;">    <a href="/Products/tabid/85/rvdsfmfid/zyxel-17/Default.aspx">
                Zyxel</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do u have the list of prefered manufactureres with you in JS?

Comment: No but it could be anything. I could maybe have an array of manufacturers I wanna display. for now i only want to display 'Xerox'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest, simply using `filter()` and `text()`:

```
// select the elements, and then filter that collection:
$('.rtLI').filter(function(){
    // keep only those elements whose trimmed-text
    // (leading/trailing spaces removed) is *not* exactly equal to the string:
    return $.trim($(this).text()) !== 'Xerox';
// hide them (or 'remove()' could be used instead):
}).hide();
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/jtqzbb50/1/) (uses the 'Zyxel' string, rather than 'Xerox', simply because you didn't include the 'Xerox'-containing element in your sample HTML).

Or you could use `remove()` to remove those non-"Xerox"-containing elements from the DOM.

With reference to the question in your comment:

> How can [I] modify this code to show more than one [manufacturer's name]. Like an array of Manufacturers?

I'd suggest:

```
// create an array of Manufacturer names to show:
var toShow = ['Zyxel', 'TP-LINK'];

$('.rtLI').filter(function(){
    // caching the trimmed-text (to make the next line clearer):
    var t = $.trim($(this).text());

    // keep only those elements whose trimmed-text is *not* in the
    // array of manufacturer names to keep (-1 is the index of not-found array
    // elements):
    return $.inArray(t, toShow) == -1;
}).hide();
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/jtqzbb50/2/)

References:

- [`$.trim()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/).
- [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/).
- [`hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/).
- [`remove()`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/).
- [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/).

Comment: THanks David. This is great. How can i modify this code to show more than one maufacturers. Like an array of Manufacturers

Comment: @MarsOne just do this. $('.rtLI').filter(function(){
    return $.trim($(this).text()) !== 'Zyxel' &&  $.trim($(this).text()) !== '2-POWER' && $.trim($(this).text()) !== 'TP-LINK' ;
}).hide();

Comment: Please don't take that approach, or you'll be fighting spaghetti code for every single change you make.

Comment: Nah, you're okay; if the answer's worth anything it'll accrue up-votes over time...thanks for the accept! And, regardless of that, I'm glad to have been of help! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can [:contains](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) selector in jquery for doing it.

Eg

```
for(var i=0; i<manufArrayToRemove.length; i++){
    var manuf = manufArrayToRemove[i];
    $(":contains('" + manuf  + "')").remove()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    $('.rtTemplate').each(function () 
    {
         var div = $(this).children()[0];

         var content = $(div).html();

         if(content != "Xerox")
            $(this).parent().parent().parent().remove();
    });
```

first u loop throught all div with class "rtTemplate" and each div u get it's child element,
and from there u get child element content with ".html()" and do the check here.

for my example, i'll remove all elements which does not have "Xerox" inside.